# Redirecting library's SLF4J logging output to my program's java.util.logging output

Tags: java, apache, slf4j, java.util.logging, sshd

I couldn't figure out from searching Stackoverflow/Google if this has been answered or if it's even possible to do. I've only found this
https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch12-logging-filter/ch12-logging-filter.html which suggests that "Once configured properly, you can continue to configure the actual logging framework you chose (e.g. modifying log4j.properties)." But I didn't know how to do that for my specific java.util.logging setup, described below.

Setup: 
I have a program that uses java.util.logging to output logging to FileHandler and ConsoleHandler. I'm using the Apache SSHD library in my program, from which I am including only [sshd-core-0.14.0.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar, slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar] specifically.

Goal: 
Logging from SSHD is currently output to the console, but not to my log file. I want to configure SSHD to route its logging to my file and/or console as I specify from within my program.

Is this even possible? Do I need to switch to another logging mechanism? I didn't think logging configuration would be this complicated and take up a not insignificant amount of time/effort.